# IOS application using swift

Tags: ios, iphone, swift

I am working on a "IOS application". I have created an application, it works fine.

If I rotate the screen some part of the application disappear. What should I do. I have also added constraints to it.

Comment: could you please provide some setting, code, etc of your app...?

Answer (score 1):

In my opinion, you didn't give enough constraints to your view. When the constraint is orange, it means it needs some more to determinate the good size. When it's blue, it means it's good.

Here's a good tutorial : http://www.raywenderlich.com/83276/beginning-adaptive-layout-tutorial